# Secure WordPress Using OpenID Connect Hybrid Flow

Tags: wordpress, identityserver4, openid-connect

I need to protect a WordPress website by using the Hybrid Flow of OpenID Connect protocol. IdentityServer4 will be used as an authority. Inside WordPress i will also host a single page application that will perform HTTP requests to a REST API (not WordPress's REST API) which is also protected by IdentityServer4. So during WordPress login i need to obtain both a cookie and an access token (that is why hybrid flow was chosen) so i can authenticate the calls to the REST API.

Is there any reliable plugin in order to achieve the described task? Do you have any alternate solution to suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about this plugin: https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/openidconnect/

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks for the answer. I am aware of the first plugin but it has some limitations. It uses only Authorization Code Flow. The other plugin has not been updated for the past 4 years so i am not really confident to use it.

Comment: It looks like it's actively maintained, so why don't you contact Jonathan? The hybrid flow is an extension of the authorization_code flow. Perhaps they can add it to the plugin. In the meantime you can use the authorization_code flow.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I will to contact him. It seems the best solution if we use a plugin. Thank you for the suggestion.